# WordPress How To create Word document from theme and run it on new order created

Tags: themes

I'm trying to make this functionality:
I have .docx template where I need to pass variables and save it in theme directory when WooCommerce order is created. But the problem is probably, that I'm badly defining path to autoload.php file.

In my theme i have correctly prepared docx templates in: `/themes/mytheme/word/vendor/phpoffice/phpword`

And the autoload.php is in `/theme/mytheme/word/vendor/autoload.php`

My PHP function is in `functions.php` of mytheme:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', function($order_id) {
    global $wp, $wpdb, $woocommerce, $post; 
    require_once '/word/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    $formatted_billing_address = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
   
    $dateofpurchase = $order->get_date_created();
    
    $result = $wpdb->get_row ( "SELECT order_item_name FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = $order_id AND order_item_type = 'line_item'" );
    $ordered_product = $result->order_item_name;
    $fullname = $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' '. $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $fullnamenospace = $order->get_billing_first_name().''.$order->get_billing_last_name();
    $filename = $fullnamenospace.'.docx';
    if($ordered_product == 'GOLD') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-gold.docx');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('address', $formatted_billing_address);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('dateofpurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
    } elseif($ordered_product == 'SILVER') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-silver.docx');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('address', $formatted_billing_address);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('dateofpurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
    } elseif($ordered_product == 'BRONZE') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-bronze.docx');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('address', $formatted_billing_address);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('dateofpurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
    } elseif($ordered_product == '3+KURZ') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-tiket3plus.docx');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('address', $formatted_billing_address);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('dateofpurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
    } elseif($ordered_product == '10+KURZ') {
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Potvrzeni-o-uzavreni-smlouvy-tiket10plus.docx');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('nameorcompany', $fullname);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('address', $formatted_billing_address);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('dateofpurchase', $dateofpurchase);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
    }
          
     

 
}, 999);
```

The order will be created with status: Waiting for Payment but in checkout I got error: `Payment processing error. Please try again.` and not .docx will be saved in my theme directory. I think that problem is in `autoload.php` path on row where I tried `require once` but I've also tried full path and it does not worked.

Edit: I've figured it out and changed my `require_once` call to:

```
require __DIR__ . '/word/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require_once( '/word/vendor/autoload.php' );` will try to load starting from the root directory of your webserver. You're probably looking for something like `require_once( './word/vendor/autoload.php' );` or perhaps `require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'word/vendor/autoload.php' );`.

(Note that [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) can be used in themes as well as plugins; the `plugin` part of its name is misleading.)